# Vuetify works dodgy in Nuxt.js project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am facing some weird issue.
Vuetify has limited functionality in my nuxt.js project.

First of all here's my default layout:

```
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <Nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

And the NavBar component overlays the page.
However the problem disappears if I remove the `app` prop from  `<v-app-bar app flat>` but then the NavBar won't be always on top of the page.
See screenshots for details:
Default view:
[image: Default view]

View with `margin-top: 100px;` on `lorem`
[image: Margin 100]

The code of `NavBar` components:

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <v-app-bar app flat>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        x-large
        class="grey--text"
        @click="drawer = !drawer"
      />
      <v-spacer />
      <v-toolbar-title>
        <a href="/">LOGO</a>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-menu offset-y>
        <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn text v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
            <!-- <v-icon>expand_more</v-icon> -->
            Dropdown menu
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.i">
            <v-list-item-action>
              <a :href="contact.link">
                <v-icon>
                  {{ contact.icon }}
                </v-icon>
              </a>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <a :href="contact.link">
                <v-list-item-title>
                  {{ contact.name }}
                </v-list-item-title></a
              >
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" bottom temporary app>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="link in links"
          :key="link.i"
          router
          :to="link.route"
          @click="refresh"
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
              <span> {{ link.name }} </span>
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    links() {
      return this.$store.state.routes
    },
    contacts() {
      return this.$store.state.contacts
    },
  },
  methods: {
    refresh() {
      if (this.drawer) {
        this.drawer = !this.drawer
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

As you can see the NavBar covers part of the content.

And another problem is that `class="mt-5 pt-5"` or any other classes about `margin` or `padding` doesn't work. `class="d-flex"` doesn't work too.

And as you can see on the screenshot, there's a `class="ml-5 pl-5 d-flex"` But there's no margin left, no padding left and the container is not flex.
[image: pl-5 ml-5 d-flex]

However

```
:class="{
      'tiny': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown,
      'large': $vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp,
    }"
```

and

```
<style>
.tiny {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: red;
}
.large {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

Does work.

And I am really confused about `vuetify` in `nuxt.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erasing and creating a new Nuxt.js project somehow helped with not working vuetify.

About margin:
The issue been solved by including NavBar (the code itself) into a `default.vue` layout AND nesting components in there.
For some reason **it doesn't work** well if I nest it **this way** in the `layouts/default.vue`:

```
<NavBar />
<Nuxt />
<Footer />
```

So the `layouts/default.vue` looks like this and **it does work** just **fine**:

```
<template>
  <v-app dark>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" bottom :fixed="fixed" app>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="route in routes"
          :key="route.i"
          :to="route.to"
          router
          exact
          @click="refresh"
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>{{ route.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="route.title" />
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar :fixed="fixed" app flat>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
      <v-spacer />
      <NuxtLink to="/">LOGO</NuxtLink>
      <v-spacer />
      <span> <a href="tel:+34XX-XXX-XX-XX">+34XX-XXX-XX-XX</a> </span>
      <DropdownWithContacts />
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <Nuxt /> <!-- the nuxt view -->
    </v-main>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <Footer />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      fixed: true,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    routes() {
      return this.$store.state.menu.routes
    },
  },
  methods: {
    refresh() {
      if (this.drawer) {
        this.drawer = !this.drawer
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>
/*a normal, unvisited link*/
a:link {
  color: green;
}
/*a link the user has visited*/
a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
/*a link when the user mouses over it*/
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
/*a link the moment it is clicked*/
a:active {
  color: brown;
}
/* removed underline */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

And I am really finding this weird. But I guess this is just the way it works.